# Format the date returned from Json

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

The date returned from Json looks like this:

2017-09-14T22:11:05.5303556

I would like it returned in a user friendly format, like:

09/14/2017 22:11:05

This is the Json:

```
[
{
id: 98,
dateCreated: "2017-09-14T22:11:05.5303556"
},
{
id: 99,
dateCreated: "2017-09-14T22:11:05.5615556"
}
]
```

And this is the JavaScript:

```
<script>            
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://mywebsite/api/Response',
            dataType: 'json',               
            success: function(json) {                       
                    myTable = $('#myTable').columns({
                    data:json,
                    schema: [
                        {"header":"ID", "key":"id"},
                        {"header":"Date", "key":"dateCreated"}
                    ],                                                          
                });                     
            }               
        });                     
</script>
```

What changes do I have to make to have the date displayed in a user friendly format? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out [10 ways to format time and date using javascript](https://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/10-ways-to-format-time-and-date-using-javascript).

You can do something like this, for example, for each of the dates:

```js
var example_date = '2017-09-14T22:11:05.5303556';

function formatDate(date) {
 var d = new Date(date),
  month = d.getMonth(),
  date = d.getDate(),
  year = d.getFullYear(),
  hours = ('0' + d.getHours()).slice(-2),
  minutes = ('0' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2),
  seconds = ('0' + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

    month++;

    return (month + '/' + date +'/' + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
}

console.log(formatDate(example_date));
```

You could also make use of `.toLocaleTimeString()` and `.toLocaleDateString()` and combine the two.

If you're not averse to using a 3rd party library, I'd recommend taking a gander at [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/). It's very good at allowing you to easily format date/time, e.g...

```
for (var i in json){
  json[i].dateCreated = moment(json[i].dateCreated).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh/mm/ss');
}
```

...where `json` is the object returned, would produce:

```
[{"id":98,"dateCreated":"09/14/2017 10/11/05"},{"id":99,"dateCreated":"09/14/2017 10/11/05"}]
```

Comment: What I don't know is how I have to edit my existing script.

Comment: Presumably you would need to add the formatting code on the first line of the success function.

If you're using moment, copy in that `for` loop I put. Otherwise, define the first function I asted and use the function like so as the first line of the success function:

`for (let i in json) {
 json[i].dateCreated = formatDate(json[i].dateCreated)
}`

Let me know if that helps?

Comment: @romsom, awesome :-) Happy to help. Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If you feel this—or any other—answer solved your issue, please consider marking it as accepted by [clicking the check mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png). This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `new Date(date).toLocaleDateString()` would get the job done

Example:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: 'http://mywebsite/api/Response',
        dataType: 'json',               
        success: function(json) {
           const data = json.map((obj) => (
              Object.assign(
                 {},
                 obj,
                 { dateCreated: new Date(obj.dateCreated).toLocaleDateString() }
              )
           ));

           myTable = $('#my-table').columns({
              data: data,
              schema: [
                 { "header": "ID", "key": "id" },
                 { "header": "Date", "key": "dateCreated" }
              ],                                                          
           });               
        }               
    });
```

I hope that helps ^__^

Comment: What I don't know is where I have to add the new lines in the script.

Comment: When I'm adding those lines I'm getting an error in the console and nothing is displayed on the page:   --->   VM238:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (00.htm:26)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.min.js:4

Comment: Again please see my updated response. It has to work now because I tested it. For simple use case like this you don't have to load a large library like momentJS.

Comment: I might have missed something but now I get the following error: index2.htm:24 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).columns is not a function
    at Object.success (index2.htm:24)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
    at done (jquery-1.12.4.js:9840)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-1.12.4.js:10311)

Answer (score 0):

Date formatting in JavaScript has been done a million times over.

If you just want a simple format, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3552493/1729458).
If you want something more robust, I would recommend [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Moment example:
`moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');`

Produces: September 15th 2017, 12:57:45 pm